# Global hooking to Cwnd::Create using MHook

Tags: c++, mfc, hook

I have been trying to hook to CWnd::Create method. I tried to hook using SetWindowsHookEx api. But this is not working consistently. So, I have followed the following blog http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49319/Easy-way-to-set-up-global-API-hooks and tried to hook to CreateWindowEx api.

Here, I am not sure whether CreateWindowEx will be called from Cwnd::Create API.

Can we hook to Cwnd::Create procedure using MHOOK? If so hooking to CreatWindowEx is the right api to listen to Cwnd::Create calls?

Comment: Are you specifically after that call, or a window being created. You can use `SetWinEventHook` for the latter.

Comment: I am interested on the window being created. But the SetWinEventHookEx is not working consistently. After googling about it many of them said SetWindowHookEx doesn't work consistently. So, I am trying with MHook library which seemed very straight forward. I am not sure whether CWnd::Create would call CreateWindowEx.

Comment: `CWnd::Create` (and `CWnd::CreateEx`) eventually call the Windows API `CreateWindowEx`. Depending on your preprocessor settings this expands to either `CreateWindowExA` or `CreateWindowExW`. MFC itself sets up a `WH_CBT` hook just before calling into `CreateWindowEx` and removes it when the call returns. If you hook `CreateWindowEx` and this call is the result of MFC creating a window make sure to follow the rules and noone gets hurt.

Comment: Do I have to put handler for CreateWindowExA and CreateWindoeExW instead of CreateWindowEx?

Comment: Also, I have a call to CWnd::Create procedure in my MFC application CWnd::Create(_T("TestClassName"), _T("hello"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0, 20, 20), this, 1234); As I am hooking to CreateWindowEx, does the classname parameter to the CreateWindowEx will have the value "TestClassName" if my hooking code hits for my MFC application window creation?

Comment: The `lpszClass` parameter represents either the class name as a string or the class `ATOM`. To distinguish between them you could probably write something like `bool isAtom = ( lpszClass < MAKEINTATOM( MAXINTATOM ) );`. Btw, this all sounds very awkward: Are you trying to hook window creation in an application for which you control the source code?

Comment: No I am not trying to hook to the window creation for which I can control the source control. To understand my code better I am testing it with a sample application.Is there a way to get the classname parameter passed for CWnd::Create API in the CreateWindowEx procedure?

Comment: Any suggestion or ideas?

Comment: if lpszClass is a string, then lpszClass can be compared with the classname provided in the Cwnd::Create api i.e TestClassName in my case. Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/e71f690a-00de-4032-95e2-21660e2235f6/setwindowshookex-on-windows-7

Not all keyboard and mouse hooks are marshalled, only globals. And marshaling of hook is performed by thread message queue. So, thread that installs hook MUST call message pumping method.