# How to check a LPCTSTR variable is null or empty

Tags: c++

the below code is not working. Here I want to check whether lpClassName is null or empty.

```
static HRESULT WINAPI ExampleMethod(
    __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpClassName)
{
    //code to check whether lpClassName is null or empty
    if( lpClassName == 0)
        return 0;

    if(*lpClassName) == L'\0')
        return 0;           
}
```

Comment: What does not work, exactly?

Comment: And what code do you want returned if both tests "pass"?  (i.e. missing `return` statement at the end).

Comment: As I [pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246601/global-hooking-to-cwndcreate-using-mhook#comment26809593_18246601), you need to check whether this is a string pointer or an `ATOM` **first**. If it is an `ATOM` you are essentially dereferencing something that is not a pointer.

Comment: @Mami Could you post code where you use this function?

Comment: Actually, I have a method where lpclassname is the input to it. I am comparing lpclassname with a string inside the method using wcscmp. The comparison is failing if the lpclassname is null. So before that comparison I would like to check whether lpclassname is null or empty.

Comment: So I would like to check whether lpclassname is null or empty. So I\I hvae been checking lpclassname==0 and *lpclassname ==L'\0'. But with the second condition I am seeing an exception with message memory not able to read.

Comment: You do **not** have a string. It is a class **`ATOM`**. Dereferencing a random `WORD` value is generally not very prudent. Read [Window Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632596.aspx).

Comment: @IInspetable, could please explain in detail? I

Comment: Answer to the question you did not ask [`GetClassInfoEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633579.aspx), but should have.

Comment: `#define S_OK ((HRESULT)0L)` - you're essentially returning a success code for both failure branches. Unrelated to your question, but you should really consider learning to walk before you attempt to run.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use a shorter form:

```
if (lpClassName == NULL || lpClassName[0] == 0)
```

There's no need to get the whole length of the string if all you need is to test for empty. The short circuit rules will prevent the second half of the statement from causing an error if the pointer is null.

Beyond that I expect the code in your question would work as well.

**Edit:** In this case the pointer appears to be coming from CreateWindowEx, which means it might not be an actual string pointer but an ATOM value instead. The way to tell the difference is to check that the upper bits are all zero. Microsoft uses the same convention for resource IDs and provides the [`IS_INTRESOURCE` macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to test for this condition.

Comment: Its not working for me. There is an exception seen here. Memory cannot be read.

Comment: Both your code as well as the code in the question fail for the same reason: `lpClassName` is not - as the question implies - actually a pointer, but rather a class `ATOM`. It would have helped **greatly** if that little detail were actually mentioned in the question...

Comment: I am new to c++ developement and may be I missed to mention an important detail of it.

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried the above code and I am getting an exception Memory canno be read. I am not sure if I am missing anything.

Comment: @Mami, what you're missing is what IInspectable mentioned - what is being called a string pointer here isn't really a string pointer. It can be in some cases but you're running into a case where it isn't. Look into the documentation for where the pointer is generated.

Comment: `if (!lpClassName || !lpClassName[0])`

Comment: @SigTerm, yes that's the hardcore way of doing it. I prefer to be more explicit, it makes it a little more readable in my opinion.

Comment: @MarkRansom: To each his own, I guess.

Comment: @Mark, I have no control on lpClassName...How can check whether lpClassName is pointer or not?

Comment: @Mami [You don't have to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314939/how-to-check-a-lpctstr-variable-is-null-or-empty#comment26883746_18314939). If you are still convinced that you do, I already explained [how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246601/global-hooking-to-cwndcreate-using-mhook#comment26809593_18246601).

Comment: @IInspectable, r u refering to this reply "Both your code as well as the code in the question fail for the same reason: lpClassName is not - as the question implies - actually a pointer, but rather a class ATOM. It would have helped greatly if that little detail were actually mentioned in the question..." . If so could you please tell me how to check whether it is a pointer or atom?

Comment: @Mami This is getting a bit ridiculous. I provided links to the documentation. You decided not to read it. I provided code to test whether the parameter is an `ATOM` or not. You chose to ignored it. I provided the API call to use so that you don't even have to know what `lpClassName` is. Again, you failed to read it or comprehend. You are immune to advice. I will no longer ignore that. And this is the end.

Comment: @IInspectble, In that reply you said 'ALL THIS is AWKWARD'and you have asked me a question. So, I thought with my answer you would suggest a different solution. I have been trying each and every solution given here in the discussion. I do take the responsibility to reply to the solutions suggested.

Comment: @IInspectable, In that reply you said 'ALL THIS is AWKWARD'and you have asked me a question. So, I thought with my answer you would suggest a different solution. I have been trying each and every solution given here in the discussion. I do take the responsibility to reply to the solutions suggested.

Comment: @Mami did you see my edit? P.S. I don't think repeating yourself is going to be productive.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I have just now checked with the new suggestion. It is excellently working. Thanks.